# ¿Por que no funciona OnClick en mi td?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente código en `jquery`, que me agrega una fila en una tabla

```
var fila = "<tr><td>" + $.trim(idProduct) + "</td>";
fila += "<td>" + $.trim(response.d.nombreProducto) + "</td>";
fila += "<td onclick='OpenModal(" + $.trim(idProduct) + ");'>XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>";
fila += "<td><center><input type='checkbox'></center></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tableccant'>1</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tablecprice'>" + response.d.precio8 + "</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tablecdescc'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td>IVA</td>";
fila += "<td>RIVA</td>";
fila += "<td>TOTAL</td>";
fila += "<td><a class='text-danger delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></tr>";
var ElementoHTML = $(fila);
$('#TableProducts').append(ElementoHTML);
```

La cual recibo unos valores mediante `ajax`, para poder crear dicha fila en la tabla.

Ahora bien dentro de una columna de esa fila, tengo un evento `onclick` al cual le envió un parámetro que en este caso es un `id`.

Este parámetro lo recibo en otra función de `jquery`, el cual esta de la siguiente manera.

```
// Función para abrir la ventana modal de las caracteristicas
function OpenModal(Product) {
    console.log(Product);
    $("#addcaract").modal();
    $("#nameProduct").text("Producto: " + Product);
    $("#priceProduct").text("Precio: ");
    $("#ivaProduct").text("IVA: ");
    $("#totalProduct").text("Total: ");
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_DropTerminado").val("XXX");
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_DropTapiz").val("XXX");
    $("#CaractCubierta").val("X");
    $("#CaractPersonalizacion").val("X");
    $("#CaractMarca").val("X");
    $("#CaractOpcion").val("X");
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando doy clic me manda el siguiente error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es lo único que me muestra, ustedes tendrán alguna solución para mi problema

Comment: `Invalid or unexpected token` es porque _sea lo que sea_ que estás enviando no tiene un formato correcto; por ejemplo; puede que el HTML que estés formando no esté generado correctamente _o un problema con las comillas en tu HTML/js, etc_. Dale click al mensaje  que aparece el error y revisa o por favor , actualiza tu pregunta con mas detalles del error.

Comment: Que tal mira, acabo de agregar una imagen del error y como ves ningún error se visualiza, te explico si no envió el parámetro no me marca error y funciona de maravilla, pero enviando el parámetro es cuando me marca el error

Comment: Ok, dale click a `Quotation.aspx:1` = inspecciona bien, si allí no ves alguna etiqueta html mal o algo, mira en la pestaña "Elements" para ver en donde se está generando el error de sintaxis (comilla faltante o algo similar).

Comment: Seguí tus pasos y no me mostraba nada en la pestaña "Elements", pero si el problema era con las comillas, lo unico que hice fue agregar esta linea `\''+idProduct+'\'`

Comment: Miguel, si esa es la solución, puedes responder a tu propia pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Claro que si Mauricio muchas gracias

Comment: Votando para cerrar como "error tipográfico".

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Les comento que mi problema tenia que ver con las comillas en donde mandaba el parámetro, mi solución fue cambiar las comillas del parámetro de la siguiente manera.

```
'<td onclick="OpenModal(\''+idProduct+'\');">XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>';
```